# Link for an image showing different image than what is found in /wp-content/uploads/

Tags: wordpress

I am using a very famous theme in its free version which utilizes an image slider on the homepage.

Suddenly, I noticed that one of the images on the slider has been changed into an inappropriate image. I ran google's `Developer tools` and got the link of the image which is: https://my-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/3.jpg

Whenever I copy and paste link into the browser I do get the false and the inappropriate image, however, when I enter the folders of the website using FTP, and visit the `/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/` and open the file `3.jpg` it shows the normal image as it is supposed to appear.

I have also checked on suspicious logins on my server and can't seem to find any.

Comment: It could be that someone has your account credentials, or some malware has infected your WP installation. Is the theme actually free or are you using a "nulled" version?

Comment: Also, this may be more suitable place to ask: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: maybe its just browser cache, hold shift and click reload to view page without cache (firefox)